In Winforms, Clicking Disable button, after enable event triggers
I have 2 buttons. Search and clear.
Search takes some time, So cursor set as waiting cursor. While search loading time. I Disable Clear button.
But i clicked disabled clear button. After search complete. I enable Clear button. After enables, Clear button click event triggers.
During Thread.Sleep time, i click disabled Clear Button
This should be error. when control is disabled, event should not trigger after enable.
when control is disabled, event should not trigger after enable.

Don't use Thread.Sleep(), this causes re-entrancy issues. Instead, mark the event handler async and await Task.Delay()

Note that any property change you do while inside an event handler is not immediately executed by the form engine. It will be executed when you exit from the event handler. So you should use your event handler to disable the button and start a separate thread for the long duration task. Winforms has a simple BackgroundWorker for these situations
